# MySQL PDO Fetchall not displaying all rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Having problems displaying all rows from database using the

```
foreach($resut as $row) { echo $row['naam']; }
```

It displays only 1 row, While there's 2 rows.

How can I solve this?

Code:

```
<?php
include('db/configuratie.php');

$key = $_GET['key'];


$validkey = array("Test123");

if (empty($key)){
  die('Geen toengansleutel opgegeven');
}


if (in_array($_GET['key'], $validkey)){

 $getrow = $database -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `contact`");
 $getrow -> execute();

 $result = $getrow -> fetchAll();

  foreach($result as $row){

    $naam = $row['naam'];


  }

  echo $naam;

}
else{
  die('Ongeldige toengangsleutel opgegeven.');

  //sla deze pogin op?
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$naam` in every loop.

To echo it immediately, you could use:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $naam = $row['naam'];
    echo $naam;
}
```

If you only want to echo naam without saving it in to a variable, you could do:

```
echo $row['naam'];
```

As a side note, do you mean "toegangsleutel" in your `die` statement?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding your `$naam` variable each row, so you are `echo`ing only the last one.

```
foreach($result as $row){
  $naam = $row['naam'];
  echo $naam;
}
```

or :

```
$naam = [] ;
foreach($result as $row){
  $naam[] = $row['naam'];
}
print_r($naam);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing   `$naam;` after the loop. You should put it in the loop. Like below.

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $naam = $row['naam'];
    echo $naam;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echo $naam should be inside the foreach loop.

something like

```
<?php
include('db/configuratie.php');

$key = $_GET['key'];


$validkey = array("Test123");

if (empty($key)){
  die('Geen toengansleutel opgegeven');
}


if (in_array($_GET['key'], $validkey)){

 $getrow = $database -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `contact`");
 $getrow -> execute();

 $result = $getrow -> fetchAll();

  foreach($result as $row){

    $naam = $row['naam'];
    echo $naam;

  }



}
else{
  die('Ongeldige toengangsleutel opgegeven.');

  //sla deze pogin op?
}
 ?>
```

or this

```
foreach($result as $row){

    echo $row['naam'];

  }
```

Why assigning it to a variable? Maybe you need it somewhere else i think